# Java Algorithm To Extract Information From a String

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, opennlp, information-extraction

I'm trying to implement a smart search feature in my application.
Usecase: The user enters the search term in a textbox

Eg: *Find me a christian male 28 years old from Brazil.*

I need to be parse the input into a map as follows:

**Gender:** male
**Age:** 38
**Location:** Brazil
**Relegion:** Christian

Already had a glance on : OpenNLP, Cross Validate, Java Pattern Matching and Regex, Information Extraction. I'm confused which one I need to look deeper into.

Is there any **java** lib already available for this specific domain?

Comment: This is very specific use case. Make a pool of word mappings and compare with your input.

Comment: "Smart" search feature? selecting these criteria from comboboxs instead of typing would be smarter for the end user, I think.

Comment: Juvanis, I know that's possible. This is a very basic usecase, it could be more complex. Initially i wanted a workaround for this scenario then take it to the next level. However, your comment made me think of adding an autocompleter in the search box as well :) . Thanks. By the way, any solution for my question?

Comment: @nanospeck Is the pattern of question fixed? Or the question can be asked in different form too? e.g. "Find me a male from Brazil who is a Christian and 28 years old" or "Find me a Christian male who is 28 and not a Christian"

Comment: rishi yes it is as u said, i can be in any different form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an API that extracts structured information (JSON) from free text: http://wit.ai

You need to train Wit with some examples of what you want to be achieved.

[image]

Comment: this is something great.. very user friendly and efficient.. although still in evolving stage.

Comment: Was not aware of this. This looks really good. Anyone looking at intent based sentences, this can be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Just an approach (there are many ways to do this I think): split your `String` in a `String[]` and process each word as you need:

```
String str = "Find me a christian male 28 years old from Brazil";
for(String s : str.split(" ")){ //splits your String using space char
    processWord(s);
}
```

Where `processWord(s)` should do something to determine if `s` is or not a key word based on your business rules.

**EDIT:** Well, as many people consider this answer insufficient I'll add some more tips.

Let's say you have a class in which you put some search criteria (assuming you want to get people that match these criteria):

```
public class SearchCriteria {
    public void setGender(String gender){...}
    public void setCountry(String country){...}
    public void setReligion(String religion){...}
    ...
    public void setWatheverYouThinkIsImportant(String str){...}
}
```

As @Sotirios pointed in his comment, you may need a pool of matching words. Let's say you can use `List<String>` with basic matching words:

```
List<String> gender = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"MALE","FEMALE","BOY","GIRL"...});
List<String> country = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"ALGERIA","ARGENTINA","AUSTRIA"...});
List<String> religion = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"CHRISTIAN","JEWISH","MUSLIM"...});
```

Now I'll modify `processWord(s)` a little (assuming this method has access to lists above):

```
public void processWord(String word, SearchCriteria sc){
    if(gender.contains(word.toUpperCase()){
        sc.setGender(word.toUpperCase());
        return;
    }
    if(country.contains(word.toUpperCase()){
        sc.setCountry(word.toUpperCase());
        return;
    }
    if(religion.contains(word.toUpperCase()){
        sc.setReligion(word.toUpperCase());
        return;
    }
    ....
}
```

Finally you need to process user's input:

```
String usersInput = "Find me a christian girl 28 years old from Brazil"; //sorry I change "male" for "girl" but I like girls :P
SearchCriteria sc = new SearchCriteria();
for(String word : usersInput.split(" "){
    processWord(word, sc);
}
// do something with your SearchCriteria object
```

Sure you can do this so much better. This is only an approach.
If you want to do the search more accurate take a read about Levenshtein's distance. It will help you for example if somebody puts "Brasil" instead "Brazil" or "cristian" instead "christian".

Comment: "Where processWord(s) should do something" does not answer the question in any way

Comment: He's asking for use Java Pattern, regex, information extraction, etc. `String.split()` uses regex as parameter so that's the answer. Then what he must to do with retrieved words are business rules. I can't tell him what to do with those words, he must to figure out for himself.

Comment: dic, I've already did it the way you explained. What I wanted was something more smarter like GATE or wit.ai.

Comment: @nanospeck I'm sorry I misunderstood the question's scope. In that case unfortunately I can't be helpful as I've never need something like that. I think the answer provided by Blacksad looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty huge area of research in language processing: it's called [Information Extraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_extraction). If it's Java you want, [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/) has pretty extensive support for IE.